# For a given $n$ the number of maximal normal subgroups is highest when it is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $n$ be fixed. Then, can we say that a group of order $n$ attains the supremum on maximal normal subgroups iff it is abelian?

I think yes. This is because, if $N$ be a maximal normal subgroup, then $G/N$ is simple. This implies that the group has the highest number of simple subgroups for a given $n$. This is, I think, only possible when the group $G$ is abelian. Am I right? Or are there counterexamples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $C_4$ has one maximal subgroup, $C_2 \times C_2$ has three, and they both have order $4$. What do you mean by "supremum on maximal normal subgroups"?

Comment: It is not "iff $G$ is abelian", because the number is larger for elementary abelian groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can suppose that the intersection of all maximal normal subgroups is trivial. But then the group is a direct product $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_k$, where each $G_k$ is either an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$, or a direct product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups.

Now an elementary abelian group of order $p^n$ has $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$ maximal normal subgroups. The only normal subgroups of $S^k$ with $S$ with nonabelian simple are the direct products of subsets of the factors, so it has only $k$ maximal normal subgroups.

So the abelian $G_i$ have many more maximal normal subgroups than the nonabelian $G_i$, for a given group order $n$, we get the largest number of maximal normal subgroups when the group is a direct product of elementary abelian groups.

The topic of the total number of maximal subgroups of a finite group is more interesting!

Comment: By elementary abelian $p-$ group I think you mean cyclic group of order $p$ right?

Comment: No, an elementary abelian $p$-group (for prime $p$) is a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$.